# How to attach base64 Screenshots for cucumber reports?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

What i have tried is,

```
final String Screenshot =((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
SCENARIO.attach(Screenshot,"image/png","BASE64");
```

or

```
SCENARIO.attach(Screenshot,"image/png:base64","Test 1");
```

**Details :**

```
io.cucumber - 6.9.1
Report - net.masterthought cucumber-reporting -5.6.1
Language -- Java
```

Comment: What kind of reports you are using?

Comment: @NandanA Cucumber  Master thoughts ( https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting )

Comment: @Hari, Is this issue solved at your end?

Answer (score 0):

To attach the screenshot as base 64 image you need capture that as `byte[]`  instead of `String`

```
@AfterStep
public void takeScreenShotAfterStep(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        final byte[] screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.attach(screenShot, "image/jpg", scenario.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Bytes[] would use  the screenshot location in the report, so that there is  a dependency the location of the screenshots placed. , to avoid is  base64 is used, so am looking solution that can help me in attaching the base64 format string in the report.

Comment: No. It won't use the location. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes it is using the location ,

Comment: href="embeddings/embedding_908296921.jpg"

Comment: this will add embedded object inside "after" wrapper object. this will not work with importing this report in Jira/Xray