# How to write a generic base64 screenshot method using selenium 4 with java and attach it to extent report on test failure?

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

method used currently

```
public static String getScreenshot(String screenshotName) throws IOException {
        String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) Base.getDriver();
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/FailedTestsScreenshots/" + screenshotName + dateName
                + ".png";
        File finalDestination = new File(destination);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);
        return destination;
    }
```

TestListener.java

```
@Override
    public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
        test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            try {

                String imgPath = Utilities.getScreenshot(result.getName());
                test.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(imgPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get the screenshot in base 64 format so that it cab be shared to anyone easily. I am using selenium version 4.0.0 and extent report version 3.1.5

Comment: Err, why do you want to turn an image into something that isn't *easily* to look at? Respectively: what is the actual problem you have with your code here?

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70216040/7731623

Comment: @GhostCat base64 screenshot will avoid screenshot location dependency. That is why i am looking for this specific location. This screenshot can also cause some problems while execution using jenkins

Comment: @NandanA your solution is not helping me.  Looking for generating screenshot in base64 format

Comment: I dont get your issue then. Turning arbitrary binary data into base 64 is a solved problem. Create a PNG, read the bytes, do the base64 encode?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement to store screenshots in base64 as reports will be shared with multiple stakeholders across my team. The following solution worked well for me.

Screenshot.java

```
public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {
        String screenshotBase64 = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
        return screenshotBase64;
    }
```

TestListener.java

```
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.fail("Test case Failed");
        test.fail("Failed step: ",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String("data:image/png;base64,"+Screenshot.getScreenshot(driver)).build());
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some methods I use for this (Base64 encoding from Joe Walnes: https://github.com/jenkinsci/xstream/blob/master/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/core/util/Base64Encoder.java ) :

```
 File full_scrn = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     full_scrn.deleteOnExit();
```

Later on I use these methods...

```
private static final char[] SIXTY_FOUR_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".toCharArray();

 public String FileToBase64(String ThisScreenshotPath)
     {
        String Base64String = "";
        Path screen_path = Paths.get(ThisScreenshotPath);
        byte[] screenshot_in_bytes = null;
         try
          {
          screenshot_in_bytes = Files.readAllBytes(screen_path);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
         System.out.println("Exception reading screenshot file: " + ex.toString()); 
          }
     Base64String = encode(screenshot_in_bytes);   
     return Base64String;
     }

public String encode(byte[] input) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    int outputCharCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i += 3) {
        int remaining = Math.min(3, input.length - i);
        int oneBigNumber = (input[i] & 0xff) << 16 | (remaining <= 1 ? 0 : input[i + 1] & 0xff) << 8 | (remaining <= 2 ? 0 : input[i + 2] & 0xff);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) result.append(remaining + 1 > j ? SIXTY_FOUR_CHARS[0x3f & oneBigNumber >> 6 * (3 - j)] : '=');
        if ((outputCharCount += 4) % 76 == 0) result.append('\n');
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

For HTML output:

```
"<img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + ThisScreenshotBase64String + "\"...
```

I do not use Extent reports, so can't help on that end.